# Does skewness predicts variance?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, skewness, shape-parameter

(with apologizes to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/39062/does-variance-predict-skewness) question).

Consider two distributions $G$, $F$ both uni-modal and absolutely continuous, square integrable and satisfying:

$$F<_c G$$

this means that the standardized distributions $F(x\sigma_F+\mu_F)$ and $G(x\sigma_G+\mu_G)$ cross each other exactly twice and that in the middle section we have that $G(x\sigma_G+\mu_G)>F(x\sigma_F+\mu_F)$, as in the example below (from [0]):

[image]

In practice,  $F<_c G$ is a convenient way to say that $G$ is more right skewed than $F$.

Now, can we say that:

$$F<_c G\implies \sigma_G^2\geq \sigma_F^2$$

? I couldn't find a proof of this,

---

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Continuous_random_variable):

> If the random variable $X$ is continuous with probability density
>   function $f(x)$, then the variance is given by
>
> $$\sigma^2_F =\int (x-\mu)^2 \, f(x) \, dx\, =\int x^2 \, f(x) \,
> > dx\, - \mu^2$$
>
> where $\mu_F$ is the expected value, $$\mu_F = \int x \, f(x) \, dx\, $$

- [0]Hannu Oja (1981).  On Location, Scale, Skewness and Kurtosis of
  Univariate Distributions. Scandinavian Journal of Statistics, Vol. 8,
  No. 3 (1981), pp. 154-168

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may depend on how one measures skewness, but if we adopt the usual [standardized third moment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Pearson.27s_moment_coefficient_of_skewness) as a measure of skewness, then the answer is "No", at least not in general: higher skewness may imply lower variance.

Consider the case of chi-squared distributions. A chi-square has variance $\sigma^2=2k$ and skewness coefficient $\gamma_1=\sqrt {8/k}$, where $k$ is the number of degrees of freedom.

Then if we have two chi-squares and it holds that

$$\gamma_{1(X)} = \sqrt {8/k_X} > \sqrt {8/k_Y}=\gamma_{1(Y)}$$

we are led to

$$\sqrt {8/k_X} > \sqrt {8/k_Y} \Rightarrow 2k_Y = \sigma^2_Y > \sigma^2_X = 2k_X
$$

This may appear counter-intuitive at first: after all as variance increases the right tail spreads more to the right, becomes fatter, so shouldn't also skewness increase?

I would say no, because the purpose here is not to have two different measures for the same thing, and this is I think why we use a skewness measure that it is, exactly, standardized with respect to the variance: to my understanding, skewness attempts to measure the *relative* degree of the fatness of a tail compared to the "tightness" of the remaining part of the distribution.

In the chi-square example, the third central moment unstandardized is a linear function of the variance -the higher the variance, the higher it will also be. But do we obtain any additional useful information this way? I wouldn't say so.
But standardized it reveals that the opposite relation holds (higher variance implies lower skewness), and if one looks at the [plots of chi-square densities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#mediaviewer/File:Chi-square_pdf.svg) as the degrees of freedom (and hence the variance) increase, I believe he may get the visual intuition as to why this is not so counter-intuitive after all: as the right tail gets thicker and spread out more to the right, the remaining part of the distribution gets less and less "uptight" (and at a "faster rate" as the skewness coefficient reveals).

Comment: @user603 You write in your question "Can we say that $$F<_c G\implies \sigma_G^2\geq \sigma_F^2 \text {?}$$", while previously you have described the left-hand side of the inequality as "$G$ is more right skewed than $F$". This is indeed a very specific question, and the one that I answered to.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, I use "the (positive) skewness coefficient of $G$ (of the $X$ variable) is greater than the (positive) skewness coefficient of $F$ (of the $Y$ variable" (which in most corners would be translated "$G$ is more right-skewed than $F$"),  and this implies for the specific chi-square case, that the variance of $G$ (of the $X$ variable) is _smaller_ than the variance of $F$ (of the $Y$ variable).

Comment: In that case, the verbal translation of the specific inequality as "$G$ is more right-skewed than $F$" is not correct in general, which further means that the concept of skewness appears not to be the appropriate way to "summarize" the inequality, and so it may have nothing or little to with what you are seeking. But then again, it may be an issue of different ways to measure "skewness".

Comment: I was wrong on the definition of $F<_c G$ in my comment (I thought $G^{-1}F(x)$ had to be *strictly* convex but it seems convexity is enough). Then, $k<l\implies\chi_l^2<_c \chi_k^2$ and your counter example stands!